# Stats/Monitor/Inspector for beanstalkd

Tags: monitoring, message-queue, beanstalkd, job-queue

Does anyone know of an app that can monitor a beanstalkd queue? I'm looking for something that shows stats on tubes and jobs, and allows you to inspect the details.

I'm not really picky about language/platform, just want to know if there's something out there before I write my own.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All of these and at least two others are listed on the beanstalkd wiki tools page:

- https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/Tools

The best ones are:

- http://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console — a web admin interface (PHP)
- http://github.com/andreisavu/django-jack — a web admin interface (Django)
- http://github.com/dustin/beanstalk-tools — a CLI admin interface

Comment: I use console(mentioned) with https://github.com/FGM/beanstalk-munin-php for munin graphs over time

Answer (score 6):

Another one is here https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console (php web monitoring interface )

Answer (score 4):

Also very new: https://github.com/denniskuczynski/beanstalkd_view  (Ruby/Sinatra app)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution based on PHP (for fast and easy deployment): [phpBeanstalkdAdmin](http://mnapoli.github.com/phpBeanstalkdAdmin/).

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of this tool ;)*

Comment: Thanks for the link, I do a log of ZF development, so that looks really useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a new Beanstalkd CLI tool. It should run on all platforms and doesn't have any dependencies.

**https://github.com/schickling/beanstalkd-cli/**

Answer (score 1):

`beanstalktop` is excellent/essential. It is a top-like interface that shows you the status of all your tubes. You get live job counts of various states for all tubes, and some general stats.

https://github.com/wewriteapps/beanstalktop

Answer (score 0):

All of these and at least two others are listed on the beanstalkd wiki tools page:

https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/Tools

Answer (score 0):

aurora: Cross-platform Beanstalk queue server console.

https://github.com/xuri/aurora